# What type of pen is being used here?

Tags: writing-instruments

Can someone please tell me what's the pen used here in the below URL called? It looks like a Gel pen, but the text written with it is so sharp:

[image]

https://www.wikihow.com/Improve-Your-Handwriting

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Is it possible to show the image here (with proper attribution of course) so that we can have a look at it without going to a different website? The goal of StackExchange is to build a repository of questions and answers that will help others with the same question in the future, so in case the website goes down that you are linking to right now or changes their links the question as it stands now is useless for future readers. Questions and answers should always stay on their own. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus. Added the image. Thanks for letting me know on the purpose of requesting the same. Will be more cautious with my future posts. Regards, Aditya

Comment: Since you mention how the text looks when written with this pen, maybe a picture of that may help?  (it's a shame there's no author bio).  It looks like a liquid ink rollerball, but quick amazon didn't show a perfect match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does not look like a Pilot G1 to me, not the point anyways.

The pen in the picture can be a [Technical pen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_pen)

Bingo: https://www.jetpens.com/Pilot-G-Tec-C-Gel-Pen-0.4-mm-Black/pd/4558

Comment: Thank you. It indeed is Pilot-G-Tec. Found this URL where you can see the zoomed version of the picture (you can see the tip and the place where you hold the pen looks almost identical) - https://goldspot.com/products/pilot-g-tec-c-blue-ultra-fine-0-4mm-gel-pen

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say from just the pics but almost certainly it's a gel rollerball pen with a very fine nib, probably ~0.5mm. Looks very much like a Pilot G1 to me.

Comment: Thank you motosubatsu. But it seems to be less than ~0.5mm. Please check this: https://www.amazon.com/CS-801-Extra-Fine-Point-0-38mm/dp/B00V6B7D9I/ref=sr_1_47?qid=1553075056&refinements=p_n_feature_two_browse-bin%3A529102011&s=office-products&sr=1-47

Comment: The G1 0.5mm nib gives a 0.32mm stroke width. It's hard to say for sure as we don't really have any definitive scale in the photos but I'm fairly confident - you don't see any shots of the pen showing a brand but in the shots you do see it positively screams G1 to me. You can get even finer gel rollerballs such as the G-Tec C4 which has a 0.4mm tip giving a 0.2mm stroke width - but that's not the pen they are using here (they have a rubber grip rather than textured). Or of course it could be a different brand I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Agreed Motosubatsu. I was just trying to highlight the TIP of both the pens as they seem almost similar.

Comment: Yes, it definitely looks like G-Tec, but rubber grip here is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit like a Pilot G-1 0.5mm. I just so happen to have one in my bag...

[image]

Also, it may be useful to you to know that these are indeed very good pens. The line is thin, sharp and consistent, and they're very smooth to write with too.